Daily time registrations in Azure DevOps REST API
We have Azure Devops where developers on a daily basis updates the Completed field. We extract this to do reporting in PowerBI. We extract items with:
https://xxx.visualstudio.com/Ad%20Hoc/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?$expand=relations&api-version=5.13
However we do not get info on how many hours the Completed column changes on a daily basis. Is there anyway to get the history on a specific field (Completed)?

There are two REST APIs you can use to get the history of Completed field.

Revisions - List: Use this API to return the list of fully hydrated work item revisions, paged.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?api-version=7.0
Sample response:




Updates - List: Returns the deltas between work item revisions.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=5.1
Sample response:



